# stop while loop with variable using button on arduino

Tags: arduino

With an Arduino I'm taking analog input from a potentiometer. With the input I regulate how much my lamp blink. The problem is when I try to have a button that turn the lamp on and off so that it blinks or not blinks. I can make the button turn on the lamp but I cannot get it to turn the lamp off.

My loop that makes the lamp blink has a variable that has to be 1 for it to run. However when i change the variable to 0 with an if statement the blink loop does not stop and the lamp keeps blinking.

Here is my code:

```
int sensorPin = A0;    // select the input pin for the potentiometer
int ledPin = 13;      // select the pin for the LED
int sensorValue = 0;  // variable to store the value coming from the sensor
int buttonPin = 11;  //select the pin for the button
int buttonState = 0; //variable to start and stop the led

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {

if(digitalRead(buttonPin)==HIGH){
  buttonState = 1;
  delay(1000) //So that buttonState does not instantly change back

  }
 if(digitalRead(buttonPin)==HIGH && buttonState == 1;){
    buttonState = 0;
    delay(1000) //So that buttonState does not instantly change back
  } 

  while(buttonState == 1){
   // read the value from the sensor:
  sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin);
  // turn the ledPin on
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  // stop the program for <sensorValue> milliseconds:
  delay(sensorValue);
  // turn the ledPin off:
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  // stop the program for for <sensorValue> milliseconds:
  delay(sensorValue);
  }

}
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: You have to change your `while(buttonState == 1)` loop. You never look inside this loop if the user has push or not the button.  (Also your second `if` is not going to work unless the user has to push the bottom for at least 1 second)

Comment: If you want to do something taking considerable time (blinking) and handle button presses in parallel, have a look (and try to understand) the BlinkWithoutDelay Sample.

Answer (score 0):

A while inside loop is always suspicious, and you provide a good example.

Inside the while loop `buttonState` will never change, thus you have a *while forever*

Simply change it to an `if` and your sketch will behave better.

Showing that `delay(1000);` is not optimal for button handling. You rather want to handle state changes (and consider bouncing buttons). But that's an advanced question. :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I changed my design so that I now have two buttons instead of one. One to turn on and one to turn off. The turn of button is supposed to change buttonState to 0 and stop the blink loop. However, it does not work and nothing happens when I press the off button. Do you have any clue of what could be wrong?

Comment: One or two buttons does not affect your underlying problem. As @Antonio also mentioned "You have to change your `while(buttonState == 1)` loop. " And, you can and should edit the code in your question, and the question itself, if appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I have changed the while loop to an if statement. However, the problem with stopping the loop still remains.